# How to tune ARIMA model to take into account a missing season?

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, arima

**Context:** a daily time series has missing measurements. I feel like it is reasonable to try to "link" observed data to interpolate these as the observed phenomenon seems to have a relatively regular seasonality. For this purpose, I tried multiple ARIMA models, including some with a Fourier term as suggested [here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/weekly.html) and put into practice [there](https://otexts.com/fpp3/dhr.html#example-australian-eating-out-expenditure).

**Problem:** one of the period is very badly interpolated and I was not able to twist the model to get the expected interpolation. My question is: "How to tune the interpolation algorithm in order to interpolate the missing values of this time serie?"

[image]

**Expected output:** the expected interpolation for the period on the right should look more like this to me (here I did some horrible cut-paste image work to showcase the expected output :p):

[image]

This question has been also poste here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/624908/227668 as I am not sure where it belongs the best.

**Example:**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
library(feasts)
library(urca)
# create the dataset
df <- tsibble::tsibble(
  date = seq(lubridate::ymd("2010-04-01"), lubridate::ymd("2022-08-31"), by = "1 day"),
  value = value, # please find the vector required below the question
  index = "date"
) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(origin = case_when(is.na(value) ~ "estimate", TRUE ~ "measure")) # create column to track interpolated values
# let's try to interpolate missing values
df %>% 
  fabletools::model(arima = fable::ARIMA(value)) %>% 
  fabletools::interpolate(df) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(dplyr::select(df, date, origin)) %>% # joining the column to track interpolated values
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = date, y = value, color = origin)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", labels = ~ lubridate::year(.x)) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Data needed to make the toy dataset:**

```
value <- c(54, 54, 57, 58, 58, 55, 53, 52, 52, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  47, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 44, 44, 43, 42, 42, 42, 42, 41, 40, 40, 
  40, 41, 42, 42, 41, 41, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 40, 39, 39, 38, 37, 
  36, 35, 34, 32, 30, 27, 25, 22, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 19, 
  19, 18, 17, 17, 19, 19, 20, 28, 31, 30, 30, 28, 26, 23, 21, 19, 
  18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
  7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 21, 38, 36, 35, 34, 38, 43, 42, 42, 41, 
  41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 
  38, 38, 39, 40, 40, 40, 42, 71, 65, 66, 60, 57, 54, 53, 52, 52, 
  52, 51, 59, 59, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 51, 50, 51, 57, 68, 
  66, 63, 61, 60, 58, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 56, 
  56, 57, 57, 57, 58, 59, 69, 66, 64, 64, 64, 64, 63, 62, 61, 61, 
  60, 60, 60, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 59, 
  59, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 60, 69, 77, 78, 76, 
  78, 77, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 71, 
  70, 69, 68, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 82, 78, 74, 73, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 85, 82, 79, 80, 78, 81, 81, 79, 76, 76, 
  75, 75, 74, 75, 75, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 79, 78, 75, 74, 73, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, 77, 74, 73, 72, 71, 71, 72, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 74, 
  74, 73, 73, 75, 75, 74, 75, 81, 77, 78, 79, 77, 75, 74, 73, 72, 
  71, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 64, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 
  20, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
  17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
  22, 21, 21, 20, 19, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
  17, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 19, 27, 31, 33, 35, 36, 36, 36, 
  36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 37, 37, 37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46, 46, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61, 60, 63, 61, 62, 61, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 57, 57, 56, 57, 59, 58, 58, 57, 56, 
  56, 56, 58, 58, 60, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 61, 61, 60, 61, 
  61, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
  60, 65, 71, 73, 76, 75, 73, 74, 73, 72, 74, 75, 74, 74, 78, 77, 
  78, 77, 77, 76, 75, 73, 74, 73, 72, 72, 72, 73, 77, 77, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, 75, 74, 74, 73, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 72, 71, 
  75, 76, 76, 75, 74, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 75, 74, 73, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 86, NA, 
  NA, NA, 79, 77, 76, 74, 74, 74, 73, 72, 71, 71, 71, 71, 78, 78, 
  78, 77, 75, 73, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 69, 69, 69, 69, 68, 67, 65, 
  63, 62, 60, 59, 57, 55, 54, 53, 53, 52, 52, 50, 49, 49, 49, 48, 
  48, 48, 58, 66, 65, 65, 62, 60, 59, 58, 59, 60, 59, 61, 60, 61, 
  65, 66, NA, NA, 70, 68, 66, 65, 65, 68, 68, 69, 68, 66, 64, 64, 
  62, 60, 59, 57, 55, 54, 55, 54, 53, 51, 50, 50, 50, 50, 48, 45, 
  41, 38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31, 39, 51, 49, 47, 
  54, 55, 65, 60, 64, 66, 61, 66, 63, 60, 59, 61, 58, 61, 64, 61, 
  59, 57, 57, 56, 55, 53, 52, 52, 57, 59, 60, 65, 63, 61, 64, 69, 
  70, 70, 69, 67, 65, 64, 62, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 59, 61, 60, 61, 
  61, 61, 61, 60, 60, 60, 62, 61, 61, 60, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 
  55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
  54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 52, 52, 51, 49, 48, 48, 47, 47, 
  47, 45, 44, 44, 42, 41, 41, 40, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 36, 
  36, 36, 36, 41, 46, 52, 65, 64, 65, 63, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 66, 
  67, 68, 67, 67, 67, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 62, 64, 64, 64, 
  68, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 72, 74, 73, 73, 73, 72, 72, 72, 
  77, 75, 73, 73, 73, 75, 76, 74, 73, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 77, 
  79, 77, 77, 80, 79, 77, 77, 76, 74, 72, 77, 79, 78, 78, 78, 77, 
  81, 78, 80, 78, 76, 76, 76, 79, 78, 76, 75, 74, 78, 77, 76, 75, 
  75, 75, 74, 74, 75, 76, 75, 76, 77, 75, 76, 77, 76, 76, 76, 77, 
  77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 78, 82, 82, 80, 78, 77, 80, 79, 79, 77, 79, 
  81, 81, 79, 79, 76, 79, 81, 78, 76, 80, 80, 79, 78, 77, 77, 75, 
  74, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 80, 79, 78, 77, 75, 74, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
  74, 75, 77, 78, 80, 82, 82, 80, 80, 79, 78, 77, 75, 74, 74, 73, 
  71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 69, 69, 69, 
  71, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 66, 66, 66, 65, 65, 65, 64, 63, 
  63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 62, 61, 61, 60, 59, 59, 67, 65, 65, 64, 
  63, 62, 62, 61, 61, 60, 68, 78, 79, 76, 74, 77, 76, 74, 71, 70, 
  71, 71, 70, 68, 66, 64, 62, 60, 57, 55, 52, 50, 50, 49, 48, 47, 
  46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 42, 49, 67, 66, 66, 64, 62, 59, 58, 57, 59, 
  57, 55, 54, 53, 53, 53, 51, 49, 46, 43, 41, 38, 37, 35, 34, 33, 
  31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 25, 25, 32, 56, 63, 60, 61, 63, 
  61, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 64, 66, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 57, 
  56, 57, 60, 59, 59, 58, 58, 60, 72, 68, 65, 64, 62, 61, 61, 60, 
  59, 59, 58, 57, 56, 56, 56, 61, 69, 67, 66, 65, 70, 69, 69, 73, 
  76, 72, 70, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 
  57, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 65, 75, 73, 74, 77, 75, 75, 75, 74, 73, 
  72, 72, 71, 71, 72, 72, 71, 70, 71, 71, 70, 70, 71, 76, 75, 75, 
  77, 77, 77, 78, 77, 78, 77, 75, 76, 77, 77, 76, 75, 75, 75, 78, 
  79, 78, 76, 75, 75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 76, 
  75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 78, 77, 76, 76, 75, 80, 79, 78, 77, 
  76, 79, 80, 78, 79, 81, 79, 79, 78, 78, 79, 78, 78, 78, 77, 76, 
  75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 80, 81, 79, 79, 78, 77, 77, 77, 79, 
  81, 80, 81, 83, 81, 81, 80, 79, 83, 80, 79, 78, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
  81, 79, 78, 79, 82, 81, 79, 78, 77, 77, 77, 78, 80, 79, 78, 77, 
  76, 76, 79, 82, 82, 81, 82, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 74, 74, 73, 72, 
  72, 71, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 69, 68, 69, 70, 72, 72, 71, 70, 69, 
  68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 65, 66, 64, 63, 63, 63, 
  63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 63, 63, 62, 
  62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 68, 73, 83, 83, 85, 82, 85, 86, 82, 
  80, 78, 77, 75, 74, 80, 82, 79, 79, 78, 80, 86, 83, 82, 80, 78, 
  76, 76, 75, 89, 90, 87, 85, 83, 82, 90, 85, 82, 80, 78, 76, 75, 
  74, 74, 73, 71, 70, 69, 67, 65, 63, 61, 59, 57, 64, 71, 71, 67, 
  64, 61, 61, 63, 64, 67, 70, 78, 82, 79, 79, 77, 74, 72, 69, 65, 
  63, 65, 68, 67, 65, 63, 61, 59, 59, 63, 66, 65, 63, 61, 60, 59, 
  58, 57, 57, 59, 59, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68, 67, 72, 71, 69, 68, 67, 
  66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 66, 73, 72, 70, 69, 69, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 
  64, 63, 63, 62, 61, 61, 60, 59, 59, 58, 57, 56, 56, 55, 55, 56, 
  61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 60, 59, 59, 58, 58, 58, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
  58, 61, 66, 64, 71, 71, 71, 70, 69, 70, 74, 72, 70, 69, 71, 74, 
  72, 72, 76, 75, 75, 74, 73, 73, 73, 73, 72, 74, 78, 76, 76, 76, 
  76, 76, 75, 75, 75, 75, 78, 82, 79, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 
  76, 76, 77, 77, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 80, 79, 79, 78, 79, 82, 82, 
  83, 84, 83, 85, 83, 82, 81, 84, 83, 82, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 79, 
  81, 85, 83, 81, 81, 82, 82, 83, 85, 84, 82, 82, 82, 84, 84, 82, 
  82, 81, 79, 82, 84, 84, 84, 83, 84, 84, 83, 83, 82, 84, 85, 85, 
  84, 83, 86, 87, 86, 87, 85, 84, 83, 83, 82, NA, NA, 80, 80, 80, 
  80, 80, 79, 79, 80, 79, 80, 79, 82, 84, 83, 85, 82, 83, 84, 84, 
  82, 82, 81, 82, 82, 81, 80, 80, 79, 78, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 76, 
  76, 75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 76, 78, 81, 79, 80, 79, 78, 
  78, 78, 79, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 73, 73, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 
  68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 60, 60, 61, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
  60, 60, 64, 64, 64, 63, 62, 61, 59, 58, 57, 56, 57, 57, 57, 56, 
  56, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 49, 48, 48, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
  46, 56, 73, 70, 67, 65, 64, 62, 60, 58, 57, 56, 55, 53, 52, 52, 
  51, 50, 50, 52, 52, 52, 51, 50, 49, 49, 48, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 
  41, 41, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
  40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
  42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 49, 60, 65, 66, 64, 68, 68, 66, 65, 63, 
  61, 63, 67, 66, 71, 72, 68, 65, 64, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62, 61, 61, 
  60, 59, 58, 58, 57, 64, 73, 72, 75, 73, 71, 71, 69, 68, 68, 70, 
  69, 70, 69, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 61, 63, 74, 73, 72, 71, 
  70, 69, 69, 68, 68, 70, 75, 75, 74, 73, 72, 72, 74, 73, 72, 71, 
  71, 70, 74, 75, 74, 73, 73, 72, 72, 71, 71, 72, 73, 72, 72, 72, 
  72, 71, 71, 71, 72, 71, 78, 76, 76, 80, 81, 81, 80, 81, 82, 81, 
  79, 79, 82, 81, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 79, 80, 81, 81, 81, 82, 
  81, 80, 81, 82, 80, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
  80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 83, 83, 82, 81, 82, 83, 82, 83, 83, 85, 85, 
  85, 84, 83, 83, 82, 80, 79, NA, NA, NA, 85, 83, 82, 81, 83, 82, 
  83, 83, 82, 82, 83, 84, 83, 81, 83, 83, 84, 86, 84, 83, 83, 84, 
  83, 82, 82, 83, 84, 84, 83, 82, 84, 82, 82, 81, 81, 80, 80, 80, 
  81, 84, 84, 86, 84, 83, 82, 82, 82, 81, 80, 79, 79, 78, 77, 78, 
  78, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 81, 82, 82, 80, 83, 82, 81, 
  80, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 77, 78, 77, 76, 76, 76, 
  75, 75, 74, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 74, 75, 76, 75, 73, 73, 
  72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 70, 78, 78, 77, 75, 75, 74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 
  72, 76, 79, 77, 75, 74, 72, 71, 71, 74, 80, 78, 78, 78, 78, 77, 
  75, 73, 72, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 73, 78, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 
  77, 76, 76, 74, 73, 72, 72, 71, 73, 75, 76, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 
  69, 68, 67, 67, 66, 67, 67, 67, 66, 66, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62, 
  61, 61, 61, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 71, 74, 72, 70, 69, 67, 
  67, 66, 66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 64, 63, 62, 62, 62, 61, 61, 60, 59, 
  58, 57, 57, 57, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 
  58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
  59, 59, 58, 58, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 56, 56, 55, 55, 55, 
  55, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
  55, 55, 55, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 58, 68, 69, 
  70, 71, 72, 73, 73, 78, 76, 75, 78, 76, 76, 76, 75, 74, 74, 74, 
  74, 74, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 72, 72, 73, 73, 
  73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 82, 80, 80, 79, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 
  77, 76, 76, 76, 78, 80, 78, 77, NA, 84, 83, 81, 81, 83, 82, 81, 
  82, 80, 79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 84, 83, 
  81, 80, 79, 82, 84, 82, 83, 82, 81, 81, 81, 82, 81, 79, 78, 77, 
  76, 76, 76, 75, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 76, 78, 81, 82, 82, 80, 82, 
  83, 83, 80, 82, 82, 80, 78, 77, 75, 75, 73, 73, 72, 73, 75, 74, 
  73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 61, 61, 60, 59, 58, 58, 
  57, 57, 56, 55, 54, 54, 53, 53, 52, 52, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
  50, 50, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 47, 47, 47, 47, 46, 46, 46, 
  46, 46, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 44, 44, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
  44, 43, 43, 42, 42, 41, 41, 40, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
  39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 
  37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
  39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 42, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
  42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
  42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 41, 41, 40, 39, 
  38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33, 33, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
  32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
  33, 33, 32, 33, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
  33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 
  39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 43, 59, 73, 73, 72, 
  70, 69, 69, 73, 72, 71, 69, 68, 71, 72, 73, 74, 80, 77, 76, 79, 
  77, 76, 76, 75, 74, 74, 77, 74, 80, 82, 80, 82, 83, 82, 81, 79, 
  80, 79, 78, 78, 77, 76, 76, 76, 77, 80, 79, 80, 82, 80, 80, 80, 
  81, 81, 79, 79, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 79, 82, 82, 81, 
  80, 82, 83, 83, 79, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 80, 80, 80, 81, 
  82, 79, 80, 81, 79, 78, 78, 84, 81, 79, 80, 83, 81, 79, 78, 78, 
  80, 78, 77, 76, 75, 75, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76, 78, 
  81, 82, 82, 81, 78, 77, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 75, 75, 75, 74, 
  73, 72, 70, 73, 79, 79, 80, 78, 77, 76, 77, 76, 75, 73, 71, 69, 
  69, 70, 68, 68, 70, 69, 68, 68, 66, 64, 62, 60, 58, 56, 55, 54, 
  53, 52, 52, 50, 50, 50, 53, 54, 53, 52, 51, 49, 47, 45, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, 38, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 36, 35, 35, 35, 36, 43, 
  44, 44, 67, 64, 61, 58, 58, 56, 53, 51, 49, 47, 45, 43, 42, 41, 
  41, 40, 40, 39, 38, 37, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 32, 31, 31, 31, 
  30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 36, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 52, 51, 
  51, 50, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 57, 58, 
  57, 56, 56, 55, 55, 55, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 
  55, 55, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 55, 54, 54, 53, 52, 52, 52, 51, 51, 
  50, 49, 48, 47, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 37, 
  36, 35, 35, 34, 34, 33, 33, 37, 43, 44, 45, 45, 45, 44, 44, 44, 
  44, 43, 43, 43, 42, 42, 42, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 40, 40, 39, 39, 
  38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 40, 43, 44, 
  45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 48, 57, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
  62, 61, 62, 62, 62, 71, 73, 72, 72, 76, 74, 72, 74, 78, 78, 77, 
  75, 75, 75, 79, 79, 77, 77, 76, 75, 74, 74, 82, 80, 78, 78, 79, 
  79, 79, 80, 79, 78, 77, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 75, 75, 75, 75, 74, 
  74, 74, 74, 75, 76, 76, 77, 76, 77, 76, 75, 76, 77, 76, 76, 75, 
  74, 74, 75, 76, 83, 81, 80, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 81, 80, 81, 80, 
  82, 80, 81, 82, 81, 79, 79, 78, 77, 77, 76, 75, 74, 74, 73, 73, 
  72, 72, 72, 71, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 76, 80, 79, 81, 80, 79, 80, 
  78, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78, 79, 
  79, 80, 79, 80, 80, 81, 80, 78, 78, 77, 77, 76, 79, 78, 79, 79, 
  79, 79, 78, 80, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 76, 
  76, 78, 77, 77, 76, 76, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 75, 75, 76, 76, 
  76, 75, 76, 79, 82, 80, 79, 81, 81, 80, 81, 80, 79, 78, 78, 78, 
  81, 81, 80, 81, 81, 79, 79, 80, 78, 81, 80, 80, 79, 79, 80, 80, 
  82, 83, 82, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 83, 82, 80, 80, 81, 82, 80, 78, 
  77, 77, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 70, 69, 68, 
  67, 67, 67, 66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 63, 63, 62, 61, 61, 60, 60, 60, 
  60, 60, 59, 58, 58, 58, 58, 57, 56, 55, 53, 52, 51, 51, 50, 50, 
  51, 55, 58, 57, 56, 56, 56, 55, 55, 54, 55, 55, 56, 55, 55, 56, 
  56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
  55, 55, 55, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 52, 
  52, 52, 51, 51, 50, 50, 49, 48, 47, 45, 44, 44, 43, 42, 42, 41, 
  41, 41, 41, 41, 40, 40, 40, 39, 39, 38, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
  37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 35, 35, 
  35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33, 33, 33, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 
  32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 35, 
  35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
  35, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 49, 70, 72, 72, 77, 80, 79, 76, 77, 76, 
  75, 74, 77, 74, 73, 72, 74, 76, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 71, 75, 75, 
  77, 76, 77, 74, 71, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 75, 75, 75, 74, 74, 
  73, 72, 73, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 75, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 73, 
  73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 80, 78, 77, 77, 77, 77, 
  77, 79, 79, 78, 78, 81, 79, 79, 78, 78, 77, 80, 81, 81, 80, 80, 
  80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 83, 81, 81, 80, 80, 80, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
  79, 82, 83, 84, 83, 81, 84, 84, 83, 81, 83, 83, 84, 84, 85, 84, 
  84, 85, 84, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 82, 81, 82, 83, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 84, 82, 80, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 75, 74, 
  74, 73, 72, 72, 81, 79, 77, 76, 75, 75, 74, 74, 77, 81, 82, 82, 
  82, 81, 81, 80, 78, 76, 75, 74, 73, 73, 73, 75, 74, 72, 70, 69, 
  68, 67, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 65, 64, 71, 78, 75, 74, 72, 71, 70, 
  68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 57, 56, 56, 55, 
  55, 54, 53, 52, 52, 51, 51, 50, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 
  50, 51, 51, 52, 52, 56, 67, 74, 69, 66, 64, 62, 59, 57, 55, 54, 
  54, 57, 57, 56, 55, 54, 52, 51, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 40, 40, 
  40, 40, 65, 72, 69, 67, 68, 67, 66, 64, 66, 67, 65, 63, 62, 64, 
  66, 65, 64, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 
  59, 58, 58, 57, 59, 64, 64, 63, 63, 62, 62, 62, 72, 71, 69, 70, 
  71, 72, 73, 74, 72, 71, 70, 70, 69, 69, 68, 68, 68, 68, 67, 66, 
  66, 65, 65, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 61, 61, 60, 
  60, 59, 59, 59, 58, 58, 58, 57, 57, 57, 57, 56, 56, 56, 55, 55, 
  55, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 71, 73, 75, 77, 74, 73, 72, 
  71, 70, 70, 70, 69, 69, 69, 68, 68, 69, 69, 71, 73, 73, 72, 72, 
  71, 71, 71, 70, 74, 78, 79, 79, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 77, 76, 76, 
  76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 78, 79, 78, 78, 77, 80, 
  82, 83, 83, 81, 82, 82, 83, 84, 83, 83, 82, 82, 83, 84, 82, 82, 
  81, 80, 79, 77, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 76, 77, 79, 81, 81, 
  81, 80, 78, 78, 77, 78, 82, 81, 81, 82, 84, 83, 82, 82, 81, 81, 
  81, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 80, 80, 80, 80, 79, 79, 79, 
  79, 79, 79, 78, 78, 77, 78, 80, 82, 80, 79, 80, 82, 81, 80, 78, 
  78, 81, 80, 79, 79, 78, 79, 79, 79, 78, 79, 79, 78, 77, 77, 76, 
  75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 70, 
  69, 69, 69, 68, 68, 68, 67, 67, 67, 67, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 
  68, 67, 67, 67, 72, 76, 73, 72, 70, 69, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 
  64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 59, 58, 56, 55, 54, 54, 53, 52, 50, 50, 
  49, 48, 47, 46, 44, 43, 41, 40, 39, 39, 38, 37, 36, 36, 35, 35, 
  35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 35, 35, 35, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
  34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 34, 33, 33, 32, 32, 31, 30, 29, 29, 29, 
  30, 31, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33, 33, 33, 33, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 
  31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
  28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
  28, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 
  28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not perfect but might be helpful in figuring out a better solution. Probably would be better to fully inspect and decompose the time series to figure out what exactly is going on but this might help already.

If you run:

```
df %>% 
  fabletools::model(ARIMA(value, trace = T))
```

You will see that you end up with a model without seasonality taken into account.

If you are more explicit what to include like for example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(fabletools)
library(fable)
library(feasts)
library(urca)

df <- tsibble::tsibble(
  date = seq(lubridate::ymd("2010-04-01"), lubridate::ymd("2022-08-31"), by = "1 day"),
  value = value, # please find the vector required below the question
  index = "date"
) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(origin = case_when(is.na(value) ~ "estimate", TRUE ~ "measure"))

df %>% 
  fabletools::model(ARIMA(value ~ trend() + season(), trace = T)) %>% 
  fabletools::interpolate(df) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(dplyr::select(df, date, origin)) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = date, y = value, color = origin)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", labels = ~ lubridate::year(.x)) +
  theme_bw()
```

You will end up with something closer to your desired output.
[image]

Idea of how to improve this further:
Use `stepwise = F` inside the `ARIMA()` function to get better results but it takes much longer to compute.
To get vastly better results one probably has to play around with adding keys to the tsibble (e.g. week or month of the year) to make it clearer for the `ARIMA()` function to search for present seasonality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not know it was possible to use `trend()` and `season()` like this. What do you mean by "adding keys [...] to make it clearer for the `ARIMA()` function to search"? It is adding week, month, etc. as explanatory variables? Ex: `ARIMA(value ~ trend() + season() + week + month)`

Comment: That would be one way that should work it I guess, but keep in mind that sometimes you 53 weeks in a year and sometimes not.
I think but I am not sure that you can corporate this directly in your tibble by using the `key = ...` argument. But this is more guesstimating and I am not confident how  to do it the correct way. Maybe somebody else can give more input.